HTML Static S3 site triggers APIG & Lambda & SES - but JSON field content not coming through into email
Have S3 Static site configured
Contact form triggers API Gateway to Lambda to SES
When receiving the email - all field content is 'undefined'
Website is successfully triggering lambda and SES
Postman is successfully triggering lambda and SES
Field content and JSON stringify not coming through correctly
Followed this link
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/
HTML Script Header
function submitToAPI(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var URL = " <URL FOR API G> ";

       var Namere = /[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z]/;
       if (!Namere.test($("#name-input").val())) {
                    alert ("Name can not less than 2 char");
           return;
       }
       var mobilere = /[0-9]{10}/;
       if (!mobilere.test($("#phone-input").val())) {
           alert ("Please enter valid mobile number");
           return;
       }
       if ($("#email-input").val()=="") {
           alert ("Please enter your email id");
           return;
       }

       var reeamil = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6})?$/;
       if (!reeamil.test($("#email-input").val())) {
           alert ("Please enter valid email address");
           return;
       }

  var name = $("#name-input").val();
  var phone = $("#phone-input").val();
  var email = $("#email-input").val();
  var desc = $("#description-input").val();
  var data = {
     name : name,
     phone : phone,
     email : email,
     desc : desc
   };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : " <URL FOR API G> ",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: "true",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),

    
    success: function () {
      // clear form and show a success message
      alert("Successful");
      document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
  location.reload();
    },
    error: function () {
      // show an error message
      alert("Unsuccessful");
    }});
}
</script>

**
HTML Contact us section**
          <form id="contact-form" method="post">
            <h4>Name:</h4>
            <input type="text" style="height:35px;" id="name-input" placeholder="Enter name here" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" /><br/>
            <h4>Phone:</h4>
            <input type="phone" style="height:35px;" id="phone-input" placeholder="Enter phone number" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"/><br/>
            <h4>Email:</h4>
            <input type="email" style="height:35px;" id="email-input" placeholder="Enter email here" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"/><br/>
            <h4>How can we help you?</h4>
            <textarea id="description-input" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></textarea><br/>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc7cVMUAAAAAM1yxf64wrmO8gvi8A1oQ_ead1ys" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></div>
            <button type="button" onClick="submitToAPI(event)" class="btn btn-lg" style="margin-top:20px; border: 2px solid #000; background-color: #fff;">Submit</button>
      </form>

Lambda - Node.js 18.x
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
const ses = new SESClient({ region: "us-east-2" });

export const handler = async(event) => {
    console.log('Received event:', event);
    await sendEmail(event);
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "body": "{ \"result\": \"Success\"}"
    };
};

async function sendEmail (event) {
    const params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
                " <email> "
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: 'name: ' + event.name + '\nphone: ' + event.phone + '\nemail: ' + event.email + '\ndesc: ' + event.desc,
                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: 'Website Referral Form: ' + event.name,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Source: " <email> ",
    };
    try {
        const data = await ses.send(new SendEmailCommand(params));
        console.log("Email sent successfully", data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}


